# How to get MediaWiki API output in old format in my browser?

Tags: java, mediawiki, wikipedia, mediawiki-api

I try to read the sections of a wikipedia article through the api through following URL:
[http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&text={{:Mozart}}__TOC__&prop=sections](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&text=%7B%7B:Mozart%7D%7D__TOC__&prop=sections)

The "old format" was a HTML like output format, which obviously has changed the last weeks. Now I get a JSON output.

How to get the old HTML format ?

I know that JSON is a better format, so please don't suggest this :-) I have my reasons to wish my old format.

Comment: HTML format of the JSON data?

Comment: No. In the past the default output was not JSON. It was kind of HTML Format. I guess there was no standard for it. It was a wikipedia output.

Comment: Yeah hard to answer because I don't know what it used to be. I do see a request format for `format=jsonfm`, which gives back the JSON  in pretty HTML format, but I'm not sure if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: I know this is hard to answer. I only hoped that someone is probably in the same situation. I'll have to rewrite all interfaces to JSON input I guess. Thanks for helping.

Comment: The documentation for the parse module is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=parse but I suggest you play around in the API Sandbox and see if you can get the results you want: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=parse&format=none&text=%7B%7BMozart%7D%7DTOC&prop=sections

Comment: Thanks. Yes I wil do. Goog Weekend !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previously, the default value for `format` was `xmlfm`, now it's `jsonfm`.

So, to get the old format, add `&format=xmlfm` to your query.

But both formats are meant for humans. If you want to actually use the API from your code, you should use one of the normal formats, like `xml` or `json`.